# Azure Data Factory If Condition Not working as expected

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have the following within the dynamic expression of an ADF IF Condition:

```
@if(equals(variables('V_D_MAX_LOAD_ID_HIS'), ''), true, equals(variables('V_D_MAX_LOAD_ID'), variables('V_D_MAX_LOAD_ID_HIS')))
```

3 Cases can occur:

1. V_D_MAX_LOAD_ID_HIS is NULL and V_D_MAX_LOAD_ID is not null

-> in this case the value shpuld be true. The first (equals(variables('V_D_MAX_LOAD_ID_HIS'), '') will be true and so we will be in the true part of the if and the output should be **true**.

2. V_D_MAX_LOAD_ID_HIS and V_D_MAX_LOAD_ID have the same value

-> in this case the first equals will be false and we will jump into the false part where the second equals is. The second equals will be true, because both have the same value. So the Output should be **true**.

3. V_D_MAX_LOAD_ID_HIS and V_D_MAX_LOAD_ID have the same value

-> The first equals will be false again, so we jump into the second equals. This one will be false to, so the output should be **false**

But for some reason it doesn't work. In the 3rd case the output for some reason is still true and the activity for true of the 'If-Conidition-activity' gets executed.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: In the 3rd case, V_D_MAX_LOAD_ID_HIS and V_D_MAX_LOAD_ID have the different value, right? If so, I have tested it and it's result is false. Can you provide us the value of V_D_MAX_LOAD_ID_HIS and V_D_MAX_LOAD_ID in the 3rd case?

Comment: OMG I took some Screenshots and I realized my mistake. I feel so stupid. When I added the V_D_MAX_LOAD_ID_HIS i jsut copied the set variable activity from the V_D_MAX_LOAD_ID which already existed. Then I never changed the variable it should be assinged to. So both Activity set the variable for V_D_MAX_LOAD_ID and V_D_MAX_LOAD_ID_HIS was never properly set. I feel so stupid. I searched for over an hour for my mistake and tried different implementations. Thanks a lot!! You helped me find my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just post an answer to end this question: This is because the variable wasn't properly set.

> When I added the V_D_MAX_LOAD_ID_HIS i jsut copied the set variable
> activity from the V_D_MAX_LOAD_ID which already existed. Then I never
> changed the variable it should be assinged to. So both Activity set
> the variable for V_D_MAX_LOAD_ID and V_D_MAX_LOAD_ID_HIS was never
> properly set.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am still new to Stackoverflow

Comment: This answer solved my problem :)